# Upstream job keeps waiting for downstream job while it has completed successfully

Tags: jenkins, hudson

We have architecture in hudson(3.3.3 we are using) where one jobs runs 3-4 downstream jobs in parallel. And after completion of downstream jobs, upstream job gets completed depending on the status of downstream jobs.

But for few jobs , i am seeing that even if the downstream job is completed successfully, upstream job keeps Waiting for the completion of downstream job. 
This is weird and happening for many of upstream jobs but not for every upstream job. Any suggestions to fix this.

i am founding recursive load and socket closed errrors in my logs.

> Apr 09, 2018 9:47:18 PM ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger warning WARNING:
>   Receive thread: error in receiveLoop: Socket closed Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive load Caused by:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive load

Comment: Have you look on hudson logs?

Comment: i am foundins recursive load and socket closed errrors in my logs.                           Apr 09, 2018 9:47:18 PM ch.ethz.ssh2.log.Logger warning
WARNING: Receive thread: error in receiveLoop: Socket closed


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive load

Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive load

Comment: add this log  in question will help others to help

Comment: thanks i have updated .

Comment: what the Hudson version are you using ?

Comment: hudson 3.3.3 version

Comment: Please try deleting _runmap.xml in your job folders and restarting the server. That should fix the problem.

Comment: did not work out..even after cleaning everything from inside job dir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168704/discussion-between-afgan-and-user2210807).

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Seems i found what was wrong here. I was cleaning all downstaream jobs and not upstream jobs. After cleaning everything from upstream and downstream, builds are working fine now. Upstream is able to get the response back from downstream and getting successfully completed.

```
/servers/hudson/jobs/upstream_job/builds/*
/servers/hudson/jobs/downstream_job1/builds/*
/servers/hudson/jobs/downstream_job2/builds*
/servers/hudson/jobs/downstream_job3/builds/*
```